# How can I get a Git log from local and/or remote HEAD?

Tags: git

I am originally an SVN user.

In Git, `git log` shows only the log from the current commit.

How can I get the log from `HEAD`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get log from server-side HEAD, you need to fetch changes from the server first. Unlike `pull`, `fetch` is not going to affect your working tree. So, it's safe.

1. `git fetch origin`

   Here `origin` is your remote repo. This command fetches the latest data from the remote repo.
2. `git log origin\master`

   Here `origin\master` implies `master` branch in the remote repo `origin`. This command shows log from `origin\master`.

Other useful `git log` options:

i) `git log HEAD..origin\master`

Show the commits that are in the "origin/master" branch but not yet in the "HEAD".

ii) `git log -p HEAD..origin\master`

Show the commits as a patch.

iii) `git log -5`

Shows the latest 5 commits.

Comment: It seems that `git log` doesn't show log from server-side `HEAD`.
After doing `git pull`,  it shows log from `HEAD`.

Comment: If you need log from server-side HEAD, then do `git fetch origin` and `git log origin\master`. These commands do not affect your working tree.

Comment: Pls take a look at my updated answer..Hope it helps you.. ;-)

Comment: I think `origin/master` is more canonical. Using backward slash isn't even supported in Linux, AFAICT.

Answer (score 3):

```
git log
```

implies

```
git log HEAD
```

`HEAD` is implied in other commands as well when issuing no reference. `HEAD` means "current commit" - regardless of what branch you are on - or even if you are not on any branch. If you want to see all references, you can do

```
git log --all --decorate
```

`all` will show you all references (tips of any branches) and their ancestors. `decorate` will mark the output commits with any references that point to them. You can make that the default behaviour for the current user with `git config --global log.decorate true`.

With the above configuration I usually do `git log --all --graph`. `graph` links each commit with ASCII art lines to see their relationships. If I want to see more information at the same time, `--oneline` is also helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As you only need one revision, run

`git log -n 1`

or

`git log -n 1 HEAD`